# What to write in Visa/Permanent resident card details (if applicable) on cathay pacific online check-in?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, check-in, cathay-pacific

I am traveling from US to India via HKG. I am going to stay in HKG for 3 days. I need help in online check-in. 
What information shall i put in Visa/Permanent resident card (if applicable)?

I am staying in US on H1B visa and citizen of India.

Comment: It may not be applicable if it's referring to [Hong Kong](https://www.chinahighlights.com/hong-kong/visa.htm): Indian nationals may enter Hong Kong visa free for 14 days, and if it's asking about *others*, if it is still valid your H1B is a non-immigrant visa (and not a resident card).

Comment: @Giorgio it seems unlikely that they'd be asking about US visas for a flight from the US.

Comment: As this is for online checkin, you don't need to fill this field in. You can put **NA** for Not Applicable.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Indian nationals do not need a visa to enter Hong Kong for up to 14 days, but you do need to fill out and print the [pre-arrival registration form](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html) before you go to the airport.

For this field in the online check-in, you may enter the notification slip number from your pre-arrival registration form.